# How to include a namespace in JsonResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Using MVC4 c# environment. 
I am needing to get a namspace to my jsonObject. Currently I am using the following structure.

```
   var results =
               Globals.StaticList
               .Where(x => x.LookupName.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
               .Select(x => new nvp()
               {
                   Name = x.LookupName,
                   ID = x.LookupName

               }).Distinct().ToArray();

          return new JsonResult() { Data = results.Take(10), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

which returns like this:

```
[{"Name":"Name 1","ID":"Name 1"},{"Name":"Name 2","ID":"Name 2"}]
```

The issue is I would like for it to return as

```
{"TheNameSpace": [{"Name":"Name 1","ID":"Name 1"},{"Name":"Name 2","ID":"Name 2"}]}
```

my nvp class looks like this:

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "TheNameSpace")]
public class nvp
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried a few different variations of DataContractSerialization like this.. but it fails miserably:

```
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (nvp[]));
        ser.WriteObject(ms,results);
        var streamreader = new StreamReader(ms);
        return streamreader.ReadToEnd();
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Create a object named "TheNameSpace" with a property wich is a list of (nvp) , that will give you that output. Fill  the "TheNameSpace" object instance and values for the nvp list.

Comment: Your model type is `IEnumerable<nvp>` while you expect to get the namespace for `nvp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
   var results =
               Globals.StaticList
               .Where(x => x.LookupName.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
               .Select(x => new nvp()
               {
                   Name = x.LookupName,
                   ID = x.LookupName

               }).Distinct().ToArray().Take(10);

return new Json(new {TheNameSpace= results},JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope will help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. It put me on the right track. There was a small issue with your syntax however.

    return Json(new {TheNameSpace = results},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);